# Is it possible to create an Android Service as a Native Extension - that would continue to run after the app has been closed?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, android-service

Using AIR's native extensions is it possible to make an Android service that would continue to run even if the App has been closed?

Comment: You can't force a program to continue running if the user of the Android device closes it.

Comment: In Android there are both running Apps and Running Services. I assumed that services were started by launching an App - but maybe they are started on install?  I certainly have Services running for Apps that I have closed.